# Use line and column numbers to map a source code variable back to its definition in a structure variable in c

Tags: c, clang, llvm

If I have a c program like this: `node_s` and `list_s` struct is defined and `list_get_first` is a function defined to get its first element data;

```
typedef struct node_s {
    void          *data;
    struct node_s *next;
    struct node_s *prev;
} Node;

struct list_s {
    size_t  size;
    Node   *head;
    Node   *tail;
};

int list_get_first(CC_List *list, void **out)
{
    if (list->size == 0)                       // list->size: 9:14
        return -1;

    *out = list->head->data;                   // list->head->data: 12:13
    return 1;
}
...
```

Suppose I can get the debug information at runtime for `list->size: 9:14` and `list->head->data: 12:13`. Is there a simple way to map that debug information back to its definition with the structure name and the associated field name automatically? I'm using clang and llvm for compilation and code analysis.

Comment: If you're compiling to ELF files you can use the DWARF debug info to get that info back. Not sure if there are any tools to read the information on PDB files.

Comment: @RedX Can you elaborate a bit more on using DWARF debug info? Assume I can use clang and llvm tools. Thanks!

Comment: Some progress has been made: I used ``clang -g`` and compile and used ``llvm-dwarfdump`` to get the all debug info and found the variables in ``.debug_line`` section, but that does not trace back to the definition of that variable. I could find the defined node and list structs in ``.debug_info`` section. But there is no direct way to associate them together.

Comment: One workaround I've come up is to find the struct variables defined in the src file and store the struct var names.  Then scan the whole module and for each load instruction I'm checking if it's trying to access a struct variable. If so, I will instrument the code and add a printer function with its debug information. Then I can compare that with debug information mentioned in the question. Not an elegant way but sufficient for my own use!

Answer (score 0):

You can write an LLVM pass to do this job.

1. First, make sure you generate debug information using '-g' in clang and emit LLVM IR using '-S -emit-llvm'
2. Create a custom LLVM pass, try to find all the variables you need.
3. For each load instruction, you have to find the definition of types of those variables. Try to get the debug information of them.
4. Create a map for each variable to its definition in struct.

The following function shows where the information you will be interested are contained in the metadata. You can get them and create the map for each variable.

```
static void findStructType(Module &M) {
  LLVM_DEBUG(M.dump());
  for (auto &F : M) {
    if (F.isDeclaration()) continue;
    for (auto &BB : F) {
      for (auto &I : BB) {
        if (I.getOpcode() == Instruction::Load) {
          if (I.hasMetadata("dbg")) {
            // This will give the line number for this load
            auto* node = dyn_cast<DILocation>(I.getMetadata("dbg"));
            node->dump();
          }
          // Here has the structure information for your structure
          if (F.hasMetadata("dbg")) {
            auto* subprog = dyn_cast<DISubprogram>(F.getMetadata("dbg"));
            subprog->getType()->dumpTree();
          }

          if (I.hasMetadata("tbaa")) {
            // This use TBAA for getting the type of this load;
            auto* tbaa = dyn_cast<MDNode>(I.getMetadata("tbaa"));  
            tbaa->getOperand(0)->dump(); // the struct type
            tbaa->getOperand(1)->dump(); // what is loading
            tbaa->getOperand(2)->dump(); // offset
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is what I can get from your example code (only the first load instruction):

```
<0x55e7875d1470> = !DISubroutineType(types: <0x55e787514828>)
  <0x55e787514828> = !{<0x55e7875cfb58>, <0x55e7875d1380>, <0x55e7875d1400>}
    <0x55e7875cfb58> = !DIBasicType(name: "int", size: 32, encoding: DW_ATE_signed)
    <0x55e7875d1380> = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_pointer_type, baseType: <0x55e7875d0230>, size: 64)
      <0x55e7875d0230> = distinct !DICompositeType(tag: DW_TAG_structure_type, name: "list_s", file: <0x55e7875cc850>, line: 9, size: 192, elements: <0x55e78755c878>)
        <0x55e7875cc850> = !DIFile(filename: "example/dwarf/p1.c", directory: "/home/riple/IPRA-exp", checksumkind: CSK_MD5, checksum: "b2e16825badf1eb53bc8cb87df801efe")
        <0x55e78755c878> = !{<0x55e7875147c0>, <0x55e7875d1280>, <0x55e7875d1300>}
          <0x55e7875147c0> = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_member, name: "size", scope: <0x55e7875d0230>, file: <0x55e7875cc850>, line: 10, baseType: <0x55e7875d0800>, size: 64)
            <0x55e7875d0800> = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_typedef, name: "size_t", file: <0x55e7875d0780>, line: 46, baseType: <0x55e7875d06c8>)
              <0x55e7875d0780> = !DIFile(filename: "install/llvm/lib/clang/16.0.0/include/stddef.h", directory: "/home/riple/IPRA-exp", checksumkind: CSK_MD5, checksum: "89af46ad12914219411a5eaafda2889f")
              <0x55e7875d06c8> = !DIBasicType(name: "unsigned long", size: 64, encoding: DW_ATE_unsigned)
          <0x55e7875d1280> = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_member, name: "head", scope: <0x55e7875d0230>, file: <0x55e7875cc850>, line: 11, baseType: <0x55e7875d1200>, size: 64, offset: 64)
            <0x55e7875d1200> = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_pointer_type, baseType: <0x55e7875d1180>, size: 64)
              <0x55e7875d1180> = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_typedef, name: "Node", file: <0x55e7875cc850>, line: 7, baseType: <0x55e7875d0c70>)
                <0x55e7875d0c70> = distinct !DICompositeType(tag: DW_TAG_structure_type, name: "node_s", file: <0x55e7875cc850>, line: 3, size: 192, elements: <0x55e787593388>)
                  <0x55e787593388> = !{<0x55e7875d0d70>, <0x55e7875d0e70>, <0x55e7875d0ef0>}
                    <0x55e7875d0d70> = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_member, name: "data", scope: <0x55e7875d0c70>, file: <0x55e7875cc850>, line: 4, baseType: <0x55e7875d0cf0>, size: 64)
                      <0x55e7875d0cf0> = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_pointer_type, baseType: null, size: 64)
                    <0x55e7875d0e70> = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_member, name: "next", scope: <0x55e7875d0c70>, file: <0x55e7875cc850>, line: 5, baseType: <0x55e7875d0df0>, size: 64, offset: 64)
                      <0x55e7875d0df0> = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_pointer_type, baseType: <0x55e7875d0c70>, size: 64)
                    <0x55e7875d0ef0> = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_member, name: "prev", scope: <0x55e7875d0c70>, file: <0x55e7875cc850>, line: 6, baseType: <0x55e7875d0df0>, size: 64, offset: 128)
          <0x55e7875d1300> = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_member, name: "tail", scope: <0x55e7875d0230>, file: <0x55e7875cc850>, line: 12, baseType: <0x55e7875d1200>, size: 64, offset: 128)
    <0x55e7875d1400> = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_pointer_type, baseType: <0x55e7875d0cf0>, size: 64)
<0x55e7875d7878> = !{!"list_s", <0x55e7875d7628>, i64 0, <0x55e7875d36d8>, i64 8, <0x55e7875d36d8>, i64 16}
<0x55e7875d7628> = !{!"long", <0x55e7875d3698>, i64 0}
i64 0
```